# Comparing 2 node sets based on attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i'm new to xslt pls provide the xslt that compare two node based on the attribute values.

input.xml:

```
<comp>
<alink>
<link id="0003"/>
<link id="0001"/>
<link id="0002"/>
 </alink>
<bibsection>
<bib id="0001">2007</bib>
 <bib id="0002">2008</bib>
<bib id="0003">2009</bib>
 </bibsection>
 </comp>
```

my output should be,

output.xml:

```
<comp>
<alink>
 <link id="0003"/><year>2009</year>
 <link id="0001"/><year>2007</year>
 <link id="0002"/><year>2008</year>
  </alink>
 <bibsection>
<bib id="0001">2007</bib>
 <bib id="0002">2008</bib>
 <bib id="0003">2009</bib>
  </bibsection>
  </comp>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A complete, efficient and short transformation, using keys**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kBibById" match="bib" use="@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="link">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <year><xsl:value-of select="key('kBibById', @id)"/></year>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<comp>
    <alink>
        <link id="0003"/>
        <link id="0001"/>
        <link id="0002"/>
    </alink>
    <bibsection>
        <bib id="0001">2007</bib>
        <bib id="0002">2008</bib>
        <bib id="0003">2009</bib>
    </bibsection>
</comp>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<comp>
   <alink>
      <link id="0003"/>
      <year>2009</year>
      <link id="0001"/>
      <year>2007</year>
      <link id="0002"/>
      <year>2008</year>
   </alink>
   <bibsection>
      <bib id="0001">2007</bib>
      <bib id="0002">2008</bib>
      <bib id="0003">2009</bib>
   </bibsection>
</comp>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies every matched node "as-is".
2. There is a single template overriding the identity template -- and it matches any `link` element. The code in the body of this template calls the identity template by name to process the matched `link` element, then constructs a `year` element, with a text node child whose value is the string value of the first `bib` element whose `id` attribute has the same value as the `id` attribute of the matched `link` element. Selecting this `bib` element is done using the **[`key()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-key)** function that references an **[`xsl:key`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)** instruction named "kBibById".

**Notice**:

The link to the identity rule above is temporarily inoperable -- for the time-being, please, use this one form the Internet Archives:

http://web.archive.org/web/20081229160200/http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html

Comment: thanks What a simple and elegant solution. suppose in my input the bib value contains child node like this.. <bib><citation>(<year>something</year>)</citation></bib> how to get that value?

Comment: @user1501710: The string value of `<bib><citation>(<year>something</year>)</citation></bib>` is "(something)". So if you want to output "something" you only need to get rid of the brackets -- use: `<xsl:value-of select="translate(key('kBibById', @id), '()', '')"/>` . It would be good if you *accept* the answer (by clicking on the check-mark next to it) and ask a new question about any new problem you have -- the comments format is inconvenient for specifying code.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Link for `identity rule` appears to be broken.

Comment: @VamanKulkarni: No, I just clicked on the link and accessed it -- *you* may have internet connection problems (likely DNS).

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - you are incorrect: that link leads to a 404.

Comment: @ABach: When I wrote my comment following the link was producing the page OK. Since then I saw a tweet by Dave Pawson that something happened to his domain name. I tried now and I still see the page -- only the images are missing. Maybe my browser cache is being used ??? Yes, after refreshing now I get 404. Here is Dave Pawson's tweet: "Dave Pawson dpawson 11h gimsieke webhost stopped support? Moved domain, waiting for dns to move, then propogate."

Comment: @ABach: I have provided another link to the page -- from the Internet Archives.